# UIprogressView Status based on text entered on UITextfield

Tags: ios

I would like to progress a `UIprogressView` Status based on the text entered in a `UITextfield`.

If I entered 3 letters, it should be `25%`, and if 5 letters it should be `50%` and so on

Comment: 3 letters - 25%.
5 letters - 50%. What kind of logic would that be ? 10 letters is the limit I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use a `textFieldDidChangeMethod`.
Since the `UITextFieldDelegate` don't have that, you can easily add behavior of your `UITextField` (or any subclassed textField for that matter) with:

```
[yourTextField addTarget:self 
                  action:@selector(textFieldDidChange) 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
```

And then in the target method:

```
- (void) textFieldDidChange
{
    float txtProgress = yourTextField.text.length / 10.0;
    [yourProgressView setProgress:txtProgress animated:YES];
}
```

**EDIT** : You can also use `UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification` as the controlEvent.
Both seem to work just fine.

Comment: your previous logic didn't really work properly so i modified it. hope you don't mind.

Comment: Not at all. Works fine in my xCode. I performed those calculations since the question wanted the progress to be 25-50-75-100 (if I understood it correctly).

Comment: well... i didn't ask the question but it would become 100% at 3 letters

Comment: Yes. My bad, the progress should have been multiplied with 0.25 instead of 25.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the TextField Delegate methods. Calculate the textfield length everytime this method is fired. Based on the length you apply you logic to update the UIProgressView.

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    NSLog(@"textFieldShouldBeginEditing");
    return YES;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{           
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidBeginEditing");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to implement delegate method of `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    int lenghtOfText = [textField.text length];

    if (lenghtOfText == 3)
    {
        // progress  25%
    }

    else if (lenghtOfText == 5)
    {
        // progress 50%
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: That a wrong way to calculate it. Because it will always lag 1 input behind what is displayed. E.g. You enter A, this method will fire BEFORE the text is changed and lengthOfText is 0, you enter B, and lengthOfText is 1 and so on. Maybe `[textField.text length] - range.length + [string length]` will do it.